# Exponential theoretical and estimated probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I have the following question to solve:

Q:Time until a metal "death" is modeled as X~Exponential (0.14).
Calculate the probability that time until death is lower or equal to 4 based on the empirical distribution function. Calculate also the theoretical value of that probability. Please indicate the absolute value for the difference between theoretical value and estimated value of that probability.

I know how to calculate the probability that time until death is lower or equal to 4 using the distribution function of exponential but what is the "theoretical value of that probability"?

Thanks

Comment: Have you stated the entire question? Perhaps the first task is to estimate the probability through simulation?

Comment: i edited with the entire question... i really can't understand... trough simulation? what do you mean?

Comment: Now that you edited the question it makes much more sense, and you can forget my comment regarding simulation. The empirical CDF at the value $4$ is given by $F_n(4)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X_i\leq 4\}}$, where $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are some observed realisations. This value is used to estimate the *theoretical value* $F(4)=P(X\leq4)$.

Comment: can you explain with the example? sorry but didn't got this part "The empirical CDF at the value 4 is given by Fn(4)=1n∑ni=11{Xi≤4}, where X1,…,Xn are some observed realisations."

Comment: I am guessing that you are taking some probability/statistics course where this is an exercise? I am certain that your book/course notes contains a definition of the empirical distribution function.

Comment: i'm confused because for my understanding,  the empirical CDF  is equal to  1 − e−λx and this is how i calculate  the theoretical value P(X<=4) but how do i calculate the "estimated" probability?

Comment: The *theoretical* CDF is $F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$. This is used to calculate the theoretical probability. The *empirical* CDF, sometimes denoted $F_n$, is a function which is calculated based on some observations $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ and its purpose is to approximate the theoretical CDF. You could call it an "estimated" CDF. The estimated probability is calculated by evaluating $F_n$ at the value $4$.

Comment: First thing is to clarify whether 0.14 is the mean $\mu$ or the rate $\lambda = 1/\mu.$ Both conventions are in common use, so it is always necessary to say which is being used in a particular case. @jakobdt is correct about the theoretical CDF (using $\lambda)$ The empirical CDF (ECDF) is based on data. .

Comment: If $\mu = \lambda = 1,$ then $P(X\le 4) = 1-e^{-4} = 0.9816844.$ If you have a sample of $n=100$ observations from such an exponential distribution in a vector `x` then the ECDF at 4 would be the fraction of elements of `x` smaller than or equal to $4.$ In my particular example $97$ of the $100$ were $\le 4$ so the ECDF at $4$ is $0.97.$ Some books might write this as $\hat F_{100}(4) = 0.97.$